Android Studioのキャッシュが原因でエラーが発生した場合には、キャッシュエラーと表示させたい
Android Studioのキャッシュが原因でエラーが発生したのですが、ログを確認してもキャッシュエラーと表示されないため、解決までに時間がかかりました。
Android Studioのキャッシュが原因でエラーが発生した場合に、キャッシュエラーと表示させるためには、どうすればよいですか？
※Android Studioでキャッシュエラーが発生する仕組と対策を理解できていないため、今後、Android Studioで発生するすべてのエラーに対して、キャッシュエラーを疑ってみることしか思いつきません……。
